# Angular2 and Typescript need to get the router params to an array of strings

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 component that calls the router to navigate to a new component. it passes a set of optional parameters and the new component needs to use them. the parameters are a set of package tracking numbers that do not have a set number and do not have different names.
I have `this.route.params` which is an Observable<>   but what I need is an array of string.
here is what starts the process:

```
private trackingNumbers: string[];
this.router.navigate(['/tracklist' , this.trackingNumbers ]);
```

so the url looks like:  localhost:3000/tracklist;0=1111;1=2222;2=333
so in the tracklist component I want to find out how many tracking numbers were passed and what they are.
I want to turn the observable params to an array of strings like it was before the navigate call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ActivatedRoute` from angular 2 router in your `tracklist component`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
        console.log(p);
    });
}
```

console.log should look like this:

> Object { 0: 1111, 1: 2222, 2:333 }

so all you have to do is to take the `p` and push it into an array or something like this.

Instead of `console.log(p)`:

```
this.myArray.push(p);
```

And now the `tracklist component` should have all the params stored in an array.

Comment: Thank you!  that was what I needed to get past the hump! I did use one more bit that I want to add here so that anyone else who is new at this can get it all working.  I added an array to my trypescript as an array of string and used the syntax :
`this.trackingNumbers = Object.values(p); `
to make the object{}  into an array of strings.